# Samba 4 permission problem, force user/group

Tags: permissions, samba

Samba is configured to use user 'torrent' and group 'users' for guest access.
I am not able to alter directory and its contents without them having g+w permissions.

I'd like to have this directory writable without g+w permissions.

What am i missing ?

My `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
security = user

map to guest = bad user
guest account = torrent

[WDC_1T]
        comment = -- WDC 1TB --
        path = /mnt/WDC_1T
        read only = no
        writeable = yes

        guest only = yes
        guest ok = yes
        force user = torrent
        force group = users
        guest account = torrent

        create mask = 0644
        force create mode = 0644
        directory mask = 0755
        force directory mode = 0755
```

created a directory via samba, everything works as supposed:

```
ls -ld _TEST_OK_/
drwxrwxr-x 2 torrent users 4096 02-27 15:42 _TEST_OK_/
```

created a directory on linux, same permissions, except not writable by group -> no write access:

```
ls -ld _TEST_PERMISSION_ERROR_/
drwxr-xr-x 2 torrent users 4096 02-27 15:40 _TEST_PERMISSION_ERROR_/

ls -lR _TEST_PERMISSION_ERROR_/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 torrent users 0 02-27 15:40 plik1.txt
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you expecting the directory created in Linux to have group write permissions?

Comment: No. I'd like to have this directory writable without g+w permissions.

Comment: If you don't grant write permission you can't write to it. Do you mean you want only the owner (user) to be able to write to it?

Comment: Simply speaking yes, i want user "torrent" to be able to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when using "force user = nobody" and "force group = nobody" on Fedora (UID 65534).

Ended up creating another user "netshare" (UID 65533) and using that as the Samba guest account and also "force user = netshare" and "force group = netshare".

Then creating files in a directory work without the group +w bit set. It's very strange but it works! Must be something with how Samba deals with certain accounts.

Comment: Don't create files/directories owned by `nobody`. It is supposed to own nothing in the filesystem